# SQL Arithmetic overflow error converting money to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

So after I received this error, I did a lot of testing to see where it was going wrong.

I ended up figuring out it was this line:

```
, Item_Cost / NULLIF(Sale_Price,0) Item_Cost_Percent
```

Both Item_Cost and Sale_Price are Money but I am assuming that this error is happening when the sale price is 0 and SQL is trying to divide Item_Cost by NULL? Is that right or should that not affect it?

What is the best way to solve this issue?

The strange part is I have almost an exact line earlier on in the code,

```
, Royalty_Cost / NULLIF(Sale_Price,0) as  Unit_Royalty_Cost_Percent
```

But that line works fine and it only gives me that error message when we reach the item_Cost line. Both item_cost and royalty_cost are Money.

```
, CAST (Item_Cost / NULLIF(Sale_Price,0) AS FLOAT ) Unit_Item_Cost_Percent
```

Gives me a Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric error. `Unit_Item_Cost_Percent` is `Numeric(5,2)` so that kinda makes sense but I have no idea why it is failing the conversion.

Comment: What do you mean, "Unit_Item_Cost_Percent is Numeric(5,2)"??   It's an alias for a calculation.  How can it have a set datatype?   Is it being inserted into another table?

Comment: Yeah I figured out the problem. Since it is 5,2, if we divide by something like .01 which will give us a very large number, it will overflow.

Comment: Why are you trying to divide by zero?